# Using JMeter SOAP/XML-RPC Request to call ChemSpell Web Service

Tags: soap, wsdl, jmeter

I'm trying to test the web service api for a free service called [ChemSpell](http://chemspell.nlm.nih.gov/spell/). I am trying to use JMeter's [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) option to test it. I am a bit new at this and not sure what to enter in. The call expects two parameters, which for testing purposes I want to set to the following:

Name = "formeldehyde"

Source = "All databases"

Based on their [site](http://chemspell.nlm.nih.gov/spell/) I'm putting "http://chemspell.nlm.nih.gov:80/axis/SpellAid.jws" for the URL and "http://chemspell.nlm.nih.gov" in Send SOAPAction.  I'm not sure how to configure the "Soap/XML-RPC Data" portion. I'm thinking the [WSDL file](http://chemspell.nlm.nih.gov/axis/SpellAid.jws?wsdl) they provide should give me everything I need to configure that section, but I'm not exactly sure how. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the xml that will be sent to the webservice, based on the wsdl, and paste it in the SOAP/XML-RPC data field.

The xml will describe the method call you wish to make and the data you wish to pass to it.

It will look like this (you will need to replace ? with data):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:spel="http://chemspell.nlm.nih.gov/axis/SpellAid.jws/axis/SpellAid.jws">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <spel:getSugList soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">?</name>
      <src xsi:type="xsd:string">?</src>
    </spel:getSugList>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The easiest way to generate blank requests like the above is using SOAP UI. You just give the wsdl URL and it generates all possible requests for you. I copy and paste these over to JMeter.